# Does a mouseover eventlistener affect performance when the mouse isn't over the attached element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, addeventlistener

Suppose you have an element that has a 'mouseover' event listener attached to it. When the mouse isn't over the listener, does the listener still affect performance?

I'm using React and mapping an array to generate a list of interactive items. When creating the JSX, I'm attaching mouseover listeners to every  item added to the list.

Since the list can grow dynamically according to user interaction, I was wondering if this design will create serious performance issues if the user creates lots and lots of list items.

I was considering adding only one listener to the list container and then trying to figure out which item was selected, but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Comment: While the mouse is not over the targeted element, then nothing should happen and that can't affect performance. So you're fine there. Of course it might incur a minimal performance penalty as attaching the first mouseover listener forces the browser to evaluate mouse position on every move, but that shouldn't be noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a high number of event listeners can indeed lead to performance issues. You mentioned adding listeners to the container which can look like this:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

parent.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
  const {target} = event;
  mouseoverChild(target);
});

parent.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
  const {target} = event;
  mouseoutChild(target);
});

function mouseoverChild(element){
  element.style.color = 'green';
}

function mouseoutChild(element){
  element.style.color = 'black';
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>First</div>
  <div>Second</div>
  <div>Third</div>
  <div>Fourth</div>
</div>
```

This will work regardless of the number of children with fewer listeners. It's not overly complicated to implement and not as expensive for the browser to handle.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to know. I didn't know that a listener attached to the parent would target the child like that. This is perfect!

Comment: Glad to help out! If you wouldn't mind accepting it as the answer I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is whether or not you need event delegation in React. In React it is unnecessary do implement event delegation in user-land. It even contradicts React's component design. React has been doing event delegation since the first release.

Further info:

- https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/07/08/react-17-event-delagation.html
- https://dev.to/maddevs/a-bit-about-event-delegation-in-react-4jeo